# CountDownTimer with notification

Tags: android, notifications, countdowntimer

I have been searching for a while now but i haven't been able to find it done before. 
What i am aiming to do is to have the user able to set their own input time in a text field and then let them set a timer that will give them a notification once the time = 0

The closest thing that i could find is [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html) which if i could get working i could simply change the time to a user input time, but with that i get an error on `mTextField`.

I assume what i am trying to do has been accomplished before but i just cant find any example of it.

Anyone got any useful links or some actual code of what it would look like?

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
At request here is what i tried, Simply made a new activity and imported the code:

```
public class TestTimer extends Activity {
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.timer_test);    

new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

     public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
         mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
     }

     public void onFinish() {
         mTextField.setText("done!");
     }
  }.start();

        }

    });     
}
```

timer_test:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/timer"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/timer" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: what error on textfield post it and some code..

Comment: @Rod_Algonquin,
Im just using the code in the link provided, All i did was create a blank activity and use that code. Its telling me that `mTextField` cannot be resolved

Comment: you need at list to show us what you did in the code.. post it.

Comment: post your timer_test xml

Comment: It literately has 1 unused button atm, But ok

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That is because `mTextField` must exist in your XML but it is not there, just try to Log.d it instead, and see the result in your logcat

**sample:**

```
    public class TestTimer extends Activity {

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.timer_test);

TextView timer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mTextField);                             
     CountDownTimer my_timer = new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

         public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
             timer.setText("Seconds remaining: "+  (millisUntilFinished / 1000));
         }

         public void onFinish() {
            timer.setText("Seconds remaining: 0 ");
         }

    };

        my_timer.start(); //call this to start the timer
}
```

Comment: I was just about to hit post your answer

Comment: `});` Syntax error on token "}", MethodHeaderName expected?

Comment: You need to add an extra `}` to properly close it (or at least i was getting an error unless i did)

Comment: What would i now need to do to get a notification from the timer, Or if i wanted to, display the timer.
The activity launched but nothing but button displayed (as expected) Logcat does successfully count down

Comment: get the reference of timer and start it.. ill edit my answer;

Comment: I managed to use **this** `public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {

            TextView timer=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.mTextField);
            
            timer.setText("Seconds remaining: "+  (millisUntilFinished / 1000));*`
But timer gets stuck at "1" Seconds left

Comment: And i did add a text with R.id `mTextField` to the xml

Comment: Have to call for the `TextView` before on each `onTick` Edited to show what i did,
Is there a way i can call for a notification once it hits 0?

Comment: @Tehjohn onFinish() method call your notification in there

Comment: Will test that out and see how i go, Thanks for being calm with me and helping me through my problem.